# extract frame from video

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimagepickercontroller

I am working an app where I have to click a video then I need all frame of that video. May I use uiimagepickercontroller to create a video. Also tell me how to extract all frame from the video and save them.
e.g. if movie is having 30 FPS
then for 1 second clip, it will extract 30 images
so for 3 seconds, 30 x 3 images

Comment: check this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/13418/how-to-play-record-edit-videos-in-ios

Comment: I think there is no any help fro frame extaction.